# Python named keyword by variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm trying to figure out if I can pass named keywords by string without calling them explicitly.
Here an example:

```
def test(height, weight):
    print("h=" + str(height))
    print("w=" + str(weight))

test(weight=1, height=2) # output

a = "weight"
b = "height"

test(a=1, b=2) # same output
```

Is this possibile?
Thanks!

Comment: Do this instead: `test(**{a:1, b:2})`

Answer (score 3):

Use a `dict`.

```
kwargs = {a: 1, b: 2}
test(**kwargs)
```

Comment: actually i answered first :) you can check the 'oldest' tab.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. Try this:

```
a = "weight"
b = "height"

kwargs = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}

test(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers are missing the point. Sure, they are correct answer to the problem you're suggesting, but they're not the answer you're looking for.

I'll condense your code a little to this:

```
def test(a):
    print(a)

test("hello, world!")  # Works!. The string is passed to the first paramater, which
                       # is 'a'.

test(a = "hello, world!")  # Works! The 'a' parameter that the function accepts is
                           # set to "hello, world".

test(b = "hello, world!")  # Fails. 'b' does not exist as a parameter in test().

b = "a"  # You're trying to set the 'b' keyword to equal the 'a' keyword here.
         # This does NOT work, which we'll see in a bit.

test(b = "Hello, world!")  # Still fails. The function checks whether 'b' exists 
                           # as a parameter. There is no such parameter.

print(b)  # Prints "a". The variable 'b' was NOT changed when test() was called.
          # You merely tried to change the parameter 'b' of the function test(),
          # which did not exist in the first place.
```